# Is this experiment describable with the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability

Consider a sequence of $100$ coin flips and let $X$ denote the number of pairs of heads, meaning coin $i$ and $i+1$ show heads but only for odd $i$. Can this experiment be described by the binomial distribution.

My thought is that one can do it.

**Edit:** What is the expected value if we allow for odd and even $i$?

My solution:$$
\mathbb{E}[ X] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^{1000} X_i X_{i+1} \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{1000}\mathbb{E}[X_i X_{i+1}] \stackrel{(1)}{=}\sum_{i = 1}^{1000}\mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_{i+1}] =\sum_{i = 1}^{1000}\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1000}{4}= 250.$$

$(1)$ We use the fact that $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ are independent.

Comment: Same as an experiment tossing two coins at a time, so....

Comment: @trueblueanil but if we were to allow odd and even $i$ this wouldn't be binomially distributed, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: As true blue anil indicated, since $i$ is restricted to odd numbers, you can construe the problem as 50 independent events, each with a success probability of $(1/4)$.  If you *change* the problem to allow $i$ both odd and even, and then clarify (for example) that a sequence that starts TTHHHT ... (i.e. Heads on coin tosses 3 through 5), constitutes 2 separate successful events (HH starting on coin toss 3 and HH starting on coin toss 4), then you have a more difficult problem, because the *events* are **no longer** independent of each other....see next comment

Comment: Analyzing this more difficult problem, it is hard to predict what form an elegant computation (if there is one) would take.

Comment: Personally, if I was attacking the more difficult problem, I would have the number of coin tosses, $(n)$ take on each value in $\{3,4,5, \cdots, 20\}.$  For each value, I would run a computer simulation to determine the expected number of successful events.  Then, I would try to study the data, trying to form a hypothesis, about the expected number of successful events, as a function of $(n)$.  So, I would be using the computer as an *analytical assistant*.

Comment: @user2661923 am I correct that the expected value for the more difficult problem, i.e. allowing odd and even $i$, is $250$?

Comment: I have no idea what the right answer to the more difficult problem is (for example, with $n=100$).  Why not edit your question to demonstrate your thinking on the more difficult problem, so that mathSE reviewers (besides me) can consider your analysis?  By the way, as I understand it, if you have 100 coin tosses, then, with the more difficult problem, there are only $(99)$ events that may or may not succeed.  Therefore, I don't understand your estimate of $(250)$ successful events.

Comment: @user2661923 I posted my thoughts

Comment: By the way, my **superficial** estimate based on [this linearity of expectation article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) is that the expected number of successful events in the more difficult problem is $(99/4).$  Unfortunately, my intuition around linearity of expectation is way too unsophisticated to state this conclustion with any confidence.

Comment: @user2661923 I forgot to mention that one also counts the pair $X_{1000}X_1$ meaning they are aligned in a cycle. So your solution was correct but with this knowledge mine should be fine.

Comment: That would change my superficial estimate, which as I indicated could be wrong, to $(100/4)$.  I don't understand your estimate of $(250)$, since there are **only** 100 coin flips.

Comment: @user2661923 because there is also the change for the pair $X_{100}X_1$ to be heads heads.

Comment: By the way, while its true that each event $X_i$ is independent of $X_{i+1}$ you are actually focusing on (for example) the event $(X_iX_{i+1})$ which is **not** independent of (for example) $(X_{i+1}X_{i+2})$.  This is why the *linearity of expectation* idea that I cited in a previous comment is critical here, **if it is appropriate**.

Comment: I think that you are confusing 100 coin flips with 1000 coin flips.

Comment: @user2661923 oh sorry! Yeah the original question is with $1000$ and I wanted to avoid unnecessary complexity when I asked the question.